# .NET Razor Model Null

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, view, model

I'm working with the .NET framework using MVC 4. I have a controller:

```
using DataProvider.Queries;
using DataProvider.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ATSGlobalDashboard.Controllers
{
    public partial class ATSNavigatorController : Controller
    {

        public virtual ActionResult Index(DataProvider.Models.GaugeAveragesViewModel model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

A model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataProvider.Models
{
    public class GaugeAveragesViewModel
    {
        public decimal? timetoresolutiontotalqtd { get; set; }
        public int? backlogtotalcount { get; set; }
        public double? AverageSatisfacationResult { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which I am then want to use for values in my view/data visuals. Part of my view is setup like this:

```
@model DataProvider.Models.GaugeAveragesViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GlobalDashboardModal";
}

<div class="row">
    <div id="satisfactionChartButton" class="large-3 large-offset-1 columns modalGaugeArea allGaugesSetup">
        <div class="chartModalTitle">Customer Satisfaction</div>
        <div id="customerSatisfactionGauge" class="gaugeContainer"></div>
        <input id="customerSatisfactionGaugeValue" value="@Model.AverageSatisfacationResult"/>
        <div class="chartModalDialog"></div>
        <div id="satisfactionOverlay">
            <div class="overlayChartTitle">Customer Satisfaction<br />
                Chart
            </div>
            <img class="overlayImages" src="@Url.Content(Links.Content.img.wht_Desktop_Analytics_png)" />
            <div class="overlayChartDialog">Click to View Chart</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to take the input value and use it with some other resources, however I am getting a null object error for the `@Model.AverageSatisfactionResult` is there anyway quickly test this, or am I leaving a step out in using the @Model razor syntax?

Comment: Could you show us your Controller code? The controller is where you need to obtain an instance and pass it into the view. The `@Model`declaration is only so you can use IntelliSense in the razorview. It doesn't do any data fetching

Comment: I added in the controller portion. Thanks.

Comment: You need a Get ActionResult method and a Post ActionResult method for Index. In your controller now, when your page is GETting, your model will be null, so you are passing a null object to your View. Is that what you want?

Comment: That is not what I want to do, I'm new to .NET and was informed passing the model like this was a method to look into.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the model to your view in the controller, then you can use the following with

```
     @model.AverageSatisfacationResult


    <input id="customerSatisfactionGaugeValue"  value="@Model.AverageSatisfacationResult"/>

Replace by

     @Html.EditorFor(m=>model.AverageSatisfacationResult)
```

@model not @Model

Edited:

I saw your controller  and it is the cause of the problem. you have the model as a parameter to the get Action, where is that coming from. If you know where it is coming from you can do the following

```
 public virtual ActionResult Index()
        {

           DataProvider.Models.GaugeAveragesViewModel model= new GaugeAveragesViewModel{
                    timetoresolutiontotalqtd =1.3,
                    backlogtotalcount=3,
                    AverageSatisfacationResult=5d
                     }
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: I added my controller code above, when I used the different model intellisense threw ; expected which I will look into.

Comment: I believe I set this up wrong based on some examples I was viewing. I am new to .NET and don't know anything about razor syntax. Is there a way you would suggest setting the controller up to best use the model values in the view?

Comment: Test it with dummy data as I did above

Comment: Thanks, that still returns a null, and if I use the lowercase model it returns Parser Error Message: Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file.

Comment: I updated the code. You view sux. I think you should be using Razor syntax. Just create the default MVC application and see how the syntax is used there